# How to obtain associate Network Adapter/Interface Speed for comparison with Network Performance Counter data in windows

Tags: windows, vb.net, network-programming

I have obtained (using vb.net) a list of my network Adapters/interfaces, which gives me a collection of Network Adapter Names, Descriptions and maximum speeds (1 Gb, 10 Gb, etc), using:

```
Dim AllNetworkInterfaces() As System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
        For Each ThisNI As NetworkInterface In AllNetworkInterfaces
            Console.WriteLine(ThisNI.Name & "    " & ThisNI.Speed & "       " & ThisNI.Description)
        Next
```

Name                       Speed        Description
"Media Network 10Gb"      100000000     "Intel Ethernet Connection Adapter #2"
(others follow)

I have also obtained a the "bytes sent/sec" performance counter for each Network Interface, i.e.

"Instance Name"                                  "bytes send/sec"
"Intel Ethernet Connection Adapter _2"         176.5

Ideally, I'd like to be able to display with my code the Adapter Name, Adapter Description, Speed (max) and actual speed (bytes send/sec). However, there doesn't seem to be a direct correlation between the Performance Counter data identifications and the Network Adapter identifications. For example, as seen above....

The GetAllNetworkInterfaces returns the NAME and SPEED, with the description containing a hash mark to identify the number of the interface.

The Performance Counter returns what it labels as the "instance name", but this is actually the "Description" of the Network Interface (NOT the Name), and the Hash mark has been replaced with an underscore.

I don't see any way to 'link' the two sets of data since the description is different between the two sets and the performance counter doesn't return the true NAME of the interface.

Is there some other method to get the actual speed of an from the performance counter along with the true name and description?

Comment: The NIC name in the collection returned by `[PerformanceCounterCategory].GetInstanceNames()` is the same as the Description member of the objects returned by `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`

Comment: ... unless you have Culture specific names. Test it in a Thread where the culture is `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Answer (score 0):

the values of descritiom and instance are similar, but not identical

But you can use simüle string replacement, to get it right

```
Dim AllNetworkInterfaces() As System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
For Each ThisNI As NetworkInterface In AllNetworkInterfaces
    Dim performanceCounterCategory As PerformanceCounterCategory = New PerformanceCounterCategory("Network Interface")
    Dim performanceCounterSent As PerformanceCounter
    Dim performanceCounterReceived As PerformanceCounter
    Dim instance() As String = performanceCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames()
    performanceCounterSent = New PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec", ThisNI.Description.Replace("(", "[").Replace(")", "]").Replace("#", "_"), True)
    performanceCounterReceived = New PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes received/sec", ThisNI.Description.Replace("(", "[").Replace(")", "]").Replace("#", "_"), True)

    Console.WriteLine(ThisNI.Name & "    " & ThisNI.Speed & "       " & ThisNI.Description & "     " & performanceCounterSent.NextValue.ToString & "     " & performanceCounterReceived.NextValue.ToString)
Next
```

This wirks on my computer, there could be more replacement needed

Comment: at first that would appear an obvious solution but is prone to failure since we have no idea how if any other characters may need to be substituted or ir leading zeroes may be introduced by this mysterious substitution (as you hinted). I'm hoping there is a more reliable method of connecting the two sets of data, or getting all the data from one 'set'.

Comment: no for your information, both tables give back not the same answer, they are quite similar, but you will not have that many characters to replace, the code should give you even for your computer the correct answer.